# undefined local variable or method f in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have been using rails for about a month, mostly loving it, sometimes infuriating (I haven't yet gotten particularly efficient at debugging through the magic).

I have a gallery page that extends from a something called simply page. Each gallery page has many gallery images.

```
class Gallery < Page
  belongs_to :page, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :gallery_images, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :gallery_images
end

class GalleryImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "600x600>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
  belongs_to :gallery
end
```

I am trying to edit the gallery through the pages controller.

```
  def edit
    @page = Gallery.find(params[:id])
    @house = @page.house
  end
```

Through the page/edit.html.erb i render the gallery form partial

```
<%= form_for @page do |f| %>
  <p><b>Images</b></p>
    <% for image in @page.gallery_images %>
        <%= image.image.url(:thumb) %>
    <% end %>

  <%= f.fields_for :gallery_images do |builder| %>
    <% render :partial => "galleries/gallery_image_fields", :f => builder %>
  <% end %>

  <p><%= f.submit %></p>
<% end %>
```

In galleries/gallery_image_fields i have

```
<p class="fields">
  <%= f.label :image %><br />
  <%= f.file_field :image %>
</p>
```

Now the urls for the above image print out so it seems that the relashionship is working fine, however I get the enormously frustrating error message.

undefined local variable or method `f' for #<#:0x210eb34>
Showing mypathblahblah/app/views/galleries/_gallery_image_fields.html.erb where line #2 raised:

**If anyone has a solution that would obviously be perfect otherwise some thoughts into how one might debug this problem would be great too. I tried outputting debug builder but it didnt really help me.**

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try changing:

```
<% render :partial => "galleries/gallery_image_fields", :f => builder %>
```

into:

```
<% render :partial => "galleries/gallery_image_fields", :locals => { :f => builder } %>
```

Comment: Thank you!!!! That works. Just out of interest, in another part of my application I am doing almost exactly the same thing and there the f => builder syntax worked fine. Why the difference?

Comment: For example in the railscast railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1 the :f => builder syntax is used. If anyone knows when to use one or the other and why I would love to know. But regardless, thanks heaps for the help.

Comment: Nick, I think if you want to use the :f => builder form, you should remove the :partial => part.